# Is this a valid question to ask (On SFSE and Overall)

Tags: discussion

I've just created a new question: [Regex replacement efficiency](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1752/regex-replacement-efficiency)

I've asked it here as it's related to (and was an offshoot from) an answer I gave yesterday however at the same time its not entirely specific to SF. It is also a question that could inspire 'discussion' rather than a straight answer.

Is it a valid question? (Ill happily remove if its not)

Comment: Leave it for now. Lets see what the community will answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely specific, sure. Regex isn't, but using regex in an apex method is clearly related to salesforce. Your question is about efficiency, which makes it clearly in context of salesforce, where your regex will be ran.

I see no reason why one should not post questions which have some salesforce relation. I think  the question is clear and clear answers could be given.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, it's a valid question, but not on SFSE.

Might be for coding, or programmers. You are asking on efficency of code, it really doesn't have much to do with SFSE.

However, I say , leave it, lets see what we can bring up as an answer.

Comment: True, but he's asking about the efficiency of using the replaceAll() Apex method which could be seen as an Apex related question.